# How do I install every libs in Devel group of Cygwin?

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin

Is there a way to install every bin in a group of softwares (like devel)?
Thank you.

Comment: Please give this an hour or two before migrating, I _think_ he's trying to get something to build and just needs to narrow down dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically? No, not that I am aware of at least. You have to go through the list and check off what you want, then apply the changes.

Due to dependencies, 'blindly' installing a whole group of programs and / or libraries would probably be a bad idea. You'd likely find that a *lot* more than what you actually wanted was pulled in, simply to satisfy dependencies.

Is there something in particular that you are trying to build? You could edit your question to reflect that, someone might be able to give you a list of 'just' what you need.